# Let $f$ continuous at $[a,b]$ and differentiable at $(a,b)$ where $f(b)=0$. How to prove that $f'(x_0) = \frac{f(x_0)}{a-x_0}$?

Tags: calculus

**The Problem**

Let $f$ continuous at $[a,b]$ and differentiable at $(a,b)$ where $f(b)=0$.

How to prove that:

$$\exists x_0 \in (a,b): f'(x_0) = \frac{f(x_0)}{a-x_0} \quad (1)$$

---

**My solution attempt**

$f$ satisfies Mean Value Theorem's requirements, thus $\exists x_o \in (a,b): f'(x_0) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} \quad (2)$

Given the fact that $f(b)=0$,

$$(2) \to f'(x_0) = \frac{f(a)}{a-b} \quad (2)$$

It seems we are getting closer to $(1)$. But we can't let $a=x_0$ because $x_o \in (a,b)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use mean value theorem on $f(x) (a-x) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the desired conclusion as
$$
 f(x) + (x-a) f'(x) = 0
$$
for some $x \in (a, b)$, and note that the left-hand side is the derivative of $(x-a)f(x)$.

This suggests to apply Rolle's theorem to $g(x) = (x-a) f(x)$.

Comment: Our responses (mine via comment to question) came at almost the same time. :)

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment only after posting the answer.

Comment: Thank you both! Could you please explain a little bit more your syllogism?

Comment: @Veriun: I have added an explanation.

Comment: @MartinR In order to apply Rolle's theorem to $g(x)$, we must choose $x_0 = \alpha$ so that $g(\alpha) = g(\beta) = 0 $. But $x_0 \in (\alpha, \beta)$ . What am I not getting?

Comment: @Veriun: Your question is not clear to me. $g$ satisfies $g(a) = g(b) = 0$. Therefore $g'(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in (a, b)$.

Comment: Your answer suggests that $g(x)$ is differentiable for $x_o = a$. We don't know this as a fact. We only know that $g(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ not $[a,b]$. I am not saying your answer is wrong (I accepted it anyway), I am just trying to clarify my confusion

Comment: @Veriun:  [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) requires  that the given function is continuous on the closed interval and differentiable on the *open* interval. It is *not required* that the function is differentiable at the endpoints of the interval.